# How are question views counted?

Tags: discussion, views

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Stack Overflow calculate the number of views in a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36728/how-does-stack-overflow-calculate-the-number-of-views-in-a-question)

Are views unique visitors? Does it include the person who was asking the question? Are only registered users counted or also people who stumble upon the question from google?

Answer (score 2):

I assume its unique views, because the number won't go up with each of my page refreshes ;)

Comment: Are you taking into account the caching of pages?

Comment: IIRC, registered users usually don't get cached pages, the last podcast talks about how they cache everything.  If it wasn't the last one, it was the one before that

Comment: They talk about caching pages in #67, but they still cache some things even if you are logged in.

Comment: They just cache much more aggressively if you are not logged in.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is based on Unique IP addresses. As you can share the question with `outsiders` like on Google+, Twitter, Email, etc. So all those people will be classed at viewers to your question too. Also, when you post a question, you will see that it has already been viewed once, that is by the asker.