# How are view counts calculated?

Tags: discussion, views

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Stack Overflow calculate the number of views in a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36728/how-does-stack-overflow-calculate-the-number-of-views-in-a-question)

How are question view counts calculated with respect to users that are logged in or anonymous?

I ask because sometimes when I ask a question on Stack Overflow, I really need to know the answer so I keep checking back on the site somewhat obsessive-compulsively.

I'm logged in every time, so does every time I go back count as a new view?  Or only if some sort cookie has expired in my browser?  Or once my user id views it, can I not create any more views?

I'm not trying to artificially inflate my views - I couldn't care less.  I just want to know why I'm not getting an answer - is it because plenty of people are looking but nobody knows, or is it because nobody is even looking?

Answer (score 5):

From [the glossary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-overflow-glossary):

#### Views

> The number of unique visitors to a question or user profile.

So, I guess only your first visit counts.

Comment: So the asker’s automated view (which occurs right after posting) counts then?

Comment: I don't think visitor IP addresses are stored forever for each page though - that would be a *huge* list to keep in the DB.

Comment: Every time I ask a question, it initially says 0 views, even if I reload several times.  Hence my uncertainty.

Comment: I know you can give a question multiple views.  to see this, pick an old question of yours, go visit, and watch the viewcount bump by one the first time (but not the 2nd).