# How come, when I added a bounty to a question, it only got one extra view?

Tags: discussion, support

So, I found a question interesting, and I added a bounty to it.  Hoping that somebody else would also find it interesting, and answer it.

But it only got 1 extra view (actually it got 4, but I think I am responsible for 3 of them).

Does this not reflect a flaw somewhere? How can someone review it, if it gets no extra views?  Was the subject really that uninteresting?

(The question in question, so to speak: [Incremental Checksums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173481/incremental-checksums) )

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Not only did you *just* start the bounty, but the question already has an accepted answer; how quickly were you expecting this to work?

Comment: Aarobot, I like your comment, I laughed at myself. Thanks. :-)   I can really see myself tapping with my fingers impatiently waiting for an answer.  But I was under the impression that if a question does not get views almost immediately, it is pushed down by other questions, never to be seen again.

Comment: Views do not affect the visibility of the question - only activity. If hundreds of people look at the question, but no one does anything, then it will still get pushed down. Hotness is calculated by views, but that question is over a year old so it will need *a lot* of views for it to even surface on that end. And even then, it's still on the Featured tab, aye?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your bounty has only existed for five hours, and checksums aren't as inviting a topic as, say, "linked lists in Java" or "integers in C#." Give it some time. I doubt that you're responsible for three of the four views, because the view counter is designed to [be pretty strict](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63104/does-viewing-your-own-question-add-to-its-view-count/63108#63108). With a 500-rep bounty, I'm sure you'll get more eyeballs soon.

That said, remember that a bounty is a promise that the question will be featured by the system. It is not a promise that the question will receive an answer, or even any views.

EDIT
In response to your comment, the [featured tab](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured) works differently than other question lists. Questions rise to the top of that list as the remaining bounty period gets shorter, so the post will actually get **more** visible as time goes on, not less.

Comment: Thanks!  This answered my question perfectly, especially with the last touch about how the question will get more visible as time goes by.

Comment: @Amigable, you're quite welcome. Now all you have to do is somehow convince about 120 other people who are offering bounties to award them immediately, so you can shoot up to the top of the featured tab today....

Comment: I don't get it.  The question will stay low today, unless 120 people add a bounty to it?! :-D

Comment: @Amigable, sorry, it was a joke, never mind. The idea was that if you got rid of the other bounty questions, your bounty would be left at the top of the featured tab.