# Can we stop increasing the "View" count on page refreshing?

Tags: support, views

I was just refreshing a Stack Overflow post, and the view count increased on every refresh.

Just out of curiosity, can we stop incrementing the view count on page refresh?

Comment: Are you sure this wasn't a coincidence? Views are tracked by IP (afaik), and not by simple pageviews.

Comment: @slhck [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63104/does-viewing-your-own-question-add-to-its-view-count#answer-310375) was an experiment to find out if your own ip counts several times

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This would be coincidence, you alone cannot increase the view count by refreshing...we intentionally prevent this from a single user (or IP), e.g. your refresh won't be counted as another page view for quite a while.