# "Viewed" increases with browser refresh (see question 108318)

Tags: bug, views

It seems that refreshing a question's page increases its viewing count. Not every time, but under certain conditions. For example, it seems that the count increases the first time a page is refreshed after it has been loaded for the first time.

If this is happening by chance, I have to visit the nearest casino asap!

I noticed this after posting a question on StackOverflow. I wanted to see whether I had a reply, so I was hitting refresh, every now and then. The count was going up every time I hadn't looked at the page for a large (arbitrary) amount of time. And every time it was going up by 1. It's not like it had received numerous views in the meanwhile. Never did I see a jump in "viewed" of more than one. And it only has 30 something views, so it's not like it's a popular question (unfortunately for me). In all actuality, there hasn't even been a single comment on it yet, let alone an answer.

All this leads me to believe that, contrary to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/108320/481292), there really is a buggy viewing count at play here. Unless it's a feature....  :)

**FINAL THOUGHTS**:
As my commenters noted, this question has been addressed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63108/481292) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90187/481292). However, **I find this feature counter-intuitive and** actually **a hindrance to users** that are *trying to see whether their question had any **true** views*. There is no point in increasing the views by taking page refresh into account. If there can be a solution that circumvents that, I would be strongly in favour of that.

Comment: Somewhere I think there's a better answer for how it works, but I think the "quite a while" in that answer is actually only about 15 minutes.

Comment: Not a bug. See Jeff answer, which is still up to date.

Comment: Regarding "visit the nearest casino", badge is given for 1000 views. Assuming 15 minutes as @Peter guessed, you'll need about 1000 * 15 minutes to get the badge, which is 625 days of refreshing a page non-stop. Lots of work to get a small badge. ;)

Comment: Also the related question I was thinking of that mentions 15 minutes which seems to be the case: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36728/how-are-the-number-of-views-in-a-question-calculated

Comment: @ShadowWizard That was my point, that this is not by chance. IF it was, I should be visiting said establishment.

Comment: Oh, thought you meant it's easy to game the system and earn badges this way. :-)

Comment: @ both ShadowWizard and PeterJ The other questions you provide are actually earlier than the question I looked at. So the thing to take home here is that nowadays there are many more people on the lookout for questions concerning viewing counters, than there were in 2011. :) In any case, case closed. Thank you very much. It's a feature, although to my view it's totally user-unfriendly.

Comment: I can't reproduce it. Maybe what you're seeing is just other users who are also viewing the question.

Comment: @DonaldDuck did you wait 15 minutes?