# How does the Stackoverflow Page View Counter work?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does stackoverflow calculate the number of views in a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36728/how-does-stackoverflow-calculate-the-number-of-views-in-a-question)

and how to prevent duplicates visit form same IP without storing huge data in mysql?

Answer (score 3):

May be you should look at following link :

- [Page View Counter like on StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246919/page-view-counter-like-on-stackoverflow)