# Are my visits to my questions accounted in "Views X times, in any case?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Stack Overflow calculate the number of views in a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36728/how-does-stack-overflow-calculate-the-number-of-views-in-a-question)

Are my visits to my questions accounted in "Views X times, in any case?

If another user repeatedly and frequently visits the same page, is every visit accounted in "View X times"?

Answer (score 0):

Visits only count if unique[trace by IP],it doesn't increase the counter if it is repeatedly and frequently visits the same page through same IP.

Comment: Any source for this?

Comment: See a link. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36728/how-does-stack-overflow-calculate-the-number-of-views-in-a-question

Comment: @Shree it's just a guess - no official member of Stack Exchange staff confirmed it just yet. I guess they have their own reasons to keep it a secret. (wild guess: to prevent people from faking views to get badges)