# How unique is profile view count?

Tags: discussion, profile-page

When is the profile view count incremented? I tried opening the page from different browsers and in incognito mode. But none of my attempts were counted. How do they realize that its me?

Comment: If I recall correctly;  the profile never counts you, or double counts "recent" people. Where recent means about 10 minutes. I believe this is IP based hence incognito mode doesn't fool it

Comment: @RichardTingle What method SO uses then? AnyWay that's not cookies. Something else

Comment: @SubinJacob These are just my recollections, they may be wrong. But I believe it is based purely on IP address; the last 10 minutes of IP addresses are cached and new IPs are checked against them

Comment: @Anna the dupe doesn't have official answer just a guess, so can you please make many people happy by revealing the actual algorithm being used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's based on IP addresses, also it'll count just one visit each hour for the same user.

Comment: Wait, so if someone re-views a question an hour later, that gets counted again, but if someone views a question while logged into their account, then someone else views the question a minute later while logged into their own account, but both are from the same network (e.g., home-router NAT), then only one view is counted? Only anonymous views should be counted per-IP, logged in users should be counted per-user.

Comment: [This post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90187/131979) seems to indicate what I suggested is indeed how it works.