# Is it possible to see who viewed my question?

Tags: discussion, questions, views

So I know that every time I refresh my question page, it increases the view count. Is there a way where I can see the IP address of the unique views on my questions?

Comment: Nope. For each question, the views+=1 when someone views it from some ip. Every 15 mins, the table of ips for that question is cleared (so if you visit the question again in >=15 mins after you visited it the previous time, you increase the view counter again)

Comment: @nicael why not post that as an answer? :)

Comment: @nicael Have you some reference for that?

Comment: @peterh http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/36728/260841

Comment: (@ᔕᖺᘎᕊ, Not posting an answer because it's a dupe for sure - and you have already found the origin of my second sentence, which I couldn't remember :)

Comment: I viewed this question, just so that you know :P

Comment: IP address?? Why not bank account?

Answer (score 7):

No, we don't currently track who the visitors are, just how many there were.