# Can I view my browsing history on a Stack Exchange site like Stack Overflow? Can I view a list of questions that I upvoted?

Tags: support, voting

When I shop on Amazon I can see my browsing history. I go to Accounts and Lists -> Browsing History and when I do so I can see every product I have clicked on in Amazon going back many months/years. I can see this as long as I was logged in when I clicked on the product. It doesn't matter what device or computer or browser I used. It shows me my history across all devices I may have logged into Amazon from and across all computers and browsers. Again, the only requirement is that I was logged in to my Amazon account when I clicked on the product.

I have included a screen capture of my Amazon browsing history
[image: Screen capture of product browsing history on Amazon]

Does Stack Overflow have a feature that allows me to see all of the questions I have clicked on (as long as I am logged in)? Does Stack Overflow have a feature that allows me to see all of the questions I have upvoted (as long as I am logged in)?

I ask because frequently I will find great posts on Stack Overflow. Often I capture the link to a great post and save it, but sometimes I forget. I will want to see the post again, if I can remember/determine which browser and which device I used, I have the web browser history I can use, but if I don't know which browser or device I used, I can't necessarily find that Stack Overflow post again.

Comment: Depending on which browser you use, it might have an option to sync your browsing history across devices.

Comment: Why do we need to see the products you buy on Amazon? I almost flagged this as spam.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars: I assume the intent was to indicate what sort of info/UI they're talking about... But yeah, it's not clearly introduced that way in the post.

Comment: @V2Blast "not clearly" is a huge understatement. Anyway, that's something the OP should fix, if they want to have decent question.

Answer (score 5):

Your votes (assuming you cast them when you had the privilege) are at https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=votes&sort=all. You can navigate to this by going to your profile and then the "Votes" tab or dropdown option. Similar lists exist for other types of actions you took on posts, such as suggesting edits, but they're not particularly easy to search.

There is no such list for questions you visited, except that your browser may keep track of that. To [track views](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90187/323179), Stack Exchange saves a record of your ID or IP address and the question you visited for about 15 minutes so it's not possible to balloon the views by refreshing the page constantly, and then that information is deleted.

If you want to keep a list of posts to revisit, Save them with the bookmark icon under the votes. (There is no way to do that automatically, unless someone made a userscript to do so.)

Comment: Only 15 minutes? My browsing habits do balloon the views, then. If I find a new question interesting or interact with it in some way, I often return several times to check new developments in intervals on the order of an hour.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek You would have to do that more than you think before it really started to matter for anything. (10 days of refreshing with no breaks would amount to about 1k views.)

Comment: This is not Stack Overflow I’m talking about here. On a small site, a question may well get only a few dozen views in total.

Comment: Sure, maybe you could double or even triple the amount of views on a question that few people are looking at. It may be *statistically* significant but it's too little to do anything mechanically (1k views needed for a bronze badge). Users also rarely care about view counts, even when it indicates a lot of real traffic.