# How do I see answers to my questions?

Tags: discussion, answers

It says 10 people saw my question but no one has bothered to answer yet. What does that mean?

Comment: Note that [views ≠ unique users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/36728/241919).

Answer (score 13):

Generally, just because someone has seen your question doesn’t mean they’ll answer it. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60290892/cors-options-preflight-requests-not-showing-in-dev-tools) over on SO has thousands of views without an answer. Views ≠ guarantee of answers

Second, your question on SO appears to be closed because it’s off-topic, which is an orthogonal issue to the views/answers. Check out the tour, read about what topics are on-topic; also search your question before asking it - I can see a closed question about [the exact same topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54530974/how-can-add-ssh-key-in-gitlab)