# What logic does Stack Overflow use calculate views on each question?

Tags: support, views

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How does stackoverflow calculate the number of views in a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36728/how-does-stackoverflow-calculate-the-number-of-views-in-a-question)
>   [How are question views counted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22752/how-are-question-views-counted)

Pardon me if this has been asked somewhere else or belongs in meta, but I'm wondering:

What logic does Stack Overflow use calculate views on each question?

There must be some code to determine a 'visit' from a view and then increment the counter for that question, but what exactly is checked/done in a scenario like this?

If anyone has any further insight to the generic problem of collecting views per piece of content, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Why the vote to close? I'd like to use similar logic in a web application I'm building - how is that off topic?

Comment: it would be better asked on meta (the stack site about stack sites) - the vote to close will automatically transfer the question to meta when enough people have voted - it's nothing personal

Comment: ...addition? :P hahahahaha

Comment: increment every time you get a hit from a unique SO account?