# Does the number of views on an SO question exclude my own views?

Tags: discussion, views

I have already read 2 other similar questions on meta - [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36728/how-does-stack-overflow-calculate-the-number-of-views-in-a-question) and [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22752/how-are-question-views-counted). However I still don't see the answer to my specific question - are my **own** views on my questions excluded from the count?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

They are included in the count. If you refresh the page after a few minutes, you will see that the counter has increased.

I discovered this feature when I periodically refreshed my question to check for new answers and comments. At every refresh, the counter increased by at least one.

---

A commenter said that s/he don't like that his/her own views are also counted on own questions. **Me neither**. A long time ago, I have created the following userscript.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           SO: Do not increase view count
// @namespace      Rob W
// @include        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10541225/*
// @include        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893269/*
// @include        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519676/*
// @include        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/*
// @run-at         document-start
// ==/UserScript==

location.href = 'javascript:(' + function(){
    var qid = '/posts/' + /\/questions\/(\d+)/.exec(location.pathname)[1] + '/ivc';
    var xhr_proto = XMLHttpRequest.prototype;
    var orig_open = xhr_proto.open;
    xhr_proto.open = function(type, url, async, username, password) {
        if ((url+'').substr(0, qid.length) === qid) {
            orig_open.call(this, 'get', '/reputation');
            console.log('Cancelled ' + url);
        } else {
            orig_open.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    };
} + ')();'
console.log('No IVC at ' + location.pathname);
```

To add a new question to the no-view list, just add `@include http://<site>/questions/<id>/*` in the meta-data section.

This is not restricted to your own questions. In fact, Using `@include *` will block the view counting on *any* site which matches the Stack Exchange's view counting method.

Use case: I want to see if my monitored questions have received any updates. When I open the question with my script enabled, I won't get the false hope that someone is looking at it ;)

Comment: And here I was thinking people were interested in my questions ;)

Comment: Uh oh ... so that means the count is not strictly reflective of the interest my question has received!

Comment: View and refresh your user profile's question list instead.

Comment: @techie.curious That's right. If you want to read your (comments/answers to) your own question without affecting the count, you can visit the [Activity/Responses tab at the profile](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/178732/techie-curious?tab=responses).

Comment: Is this not a bug? I for one do not like that my own views are counted...

Comment: @Curious Me neither. I have written a userscript which prevents my own views from being counted on my own questions (for convenience, the IDs are hard-coded; I have only 2 questions, so that's maintainable). I'll edit my answer to include that script, in case anyone wants it.

Comment: @Curious No problem. I think that you might also be interested in my ["View vote totals without 1000 rep"](http://stackapps.com/q/3082/9699?view-vote-totals-without-1000-rep) script. It allows you to view the +/- votes on a post.

Comment: Is there a feature request for not having my own views counted? (I'm pretty sure I've a question with 46 views where 40 of them are easily my own!)

Comment: From a "technically" standpoint, it is correct to count the profile view (page hit) when the user visits his own profile. However, from a "usability" standpoint it is nonsense. And it also removes the information when a third person visited his profile.

Comment: @user399844 feature request/bug report here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141416/do-not-count-views-of-the-asker/348315#348315