# It is a probable bug in badge "Popular Question"?

Tags: support, badges, views

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do not count views of the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141416/do-not-count-views-of-the-asker)

Shouldn't it be avoided that the number of visits to one's own question increases the view count?

If I delete the cache, and then visit a question of my own, it will increase the number of views.

That way you could get the badge "Popular Question" improperly.

Comment: Why is it inappropriate my question?

Comment: try yourself ... i am pretty sure you wont do more than 20 time ...

Comment: -1 because "If I delete the cache, and then visit a question of my own, it will increase the number of views" is just wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm really not sure this is an actual problem. If someone finds the time to try to game the system to earn a bronze badge, one which still requires 1000 visits, then that person has bigger problems than badges on a Q&A site.

This would take a long time, and it would be extremely boring and repetitive. It might also help you gain the carpal tunnel badge. :)

All joking aside, someone would do much better to actively contribute to the site in a positive manner. Earning that bronze badge in the manner you describe involves a person putting in lots and lots of inputs for very little and unrewarding outputs.

I'm not going to go into the details involved in gaming the system to earn this badge, because I don't want to encourage this type of behavior.

Instead, focus on great Q&A, and the reputation and badges will come. In addition to this, you get to feel the satisfaction of knowing that you've helped someone, whereas earning a stupid badge may earn you a good feeling only for a few seconds... and for nothing...

Comment: jmort253 Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 4):

Just to clarify the main point in this question:

> If I delete the cache, and then visit a question of my own, it will increase the number of views.

...no, no it won't.