# Change "viewed X times" to "viewed by X users"

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, views

I recently conducted an experiment in which I tried to increase the view count on an old question several different ways:

- reloading the page
- going to a different question and back
- leaving for 15 minutes and coming back again

However, the view count on the question stayed the same.

Judging by this, I take it that the view count is really the number of viewers that have viewed the question.

Taking that into account, can we change this:

[image: view count]

to better reflect what the count really is?

viewed by 390 users

Any suggestions/comments appreciated.

Comment: But the # of views ≠ number of users who viewed the question. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90187/323179) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/122173/323179).

Answer (score 5):

I'd expect that

> leaving for 15 minutes and coming back again

would increase the view count; perhaps you should try reloading the page again after a while, since the view count is cached. Or wait a little longer than 15 minutes? [This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90187/295232) elaborates:

> There is some sort of a throttling mechanism in action. It saves the information about a question view per visitor like in pairs:
>
> - for anonymous users, it is `IP + QuestionNr`.
> - for authenticated users it is `UserNr + QuestionNr`.
>
> This information is saved in an expiring cache entry for about 15 minutes. If a subsequent hit sees the entry is still there it discards the new hit. If it is already gone it allows for a new record.

and from my (earlier) tests I am *definitely* able to increase the view count on my own multiple times.

Comment: Yep, tried after 16 minutes and the vote count increased. Thanks.